# How to return bool from a button click in alert with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, boolean

```
 override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
        let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
            showCloseButton: false,
            showCircularIcon: false
        )
        let alertView = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
        alertView.addButton("First") {
            return true
        }
        alertView.addButton("Second") {
            return false
        }

        alertView.showSuccess("warning", subTitle: "something")


    }
```

This code above wants a `return true/false` before the last curly bracket but if I do that I lose the button return.

So is there any way to archive this?

I use `SCLAlertView` for my alert (if someone knows how to do it with uialert I would like to see it)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use an alert (that will have an "async" answer) in that method. Create a different method with it before and according to that value, perform the segue: Replace `return true` with `self.performSegue(...)`

Comment: @Larme so should I put the alert inside `didselect` function and then I'll use the `self.performSegue(...)`?

Comment: Create a method `showAlert()`. In `didSelect()`, call `showAlert()`. In case of "First", call `self.performSegue()`.

Comment: Should i delete the segue from the storyboard?

Comment: @mikevorisis How your segue is connected in your storyboard?

Comment: I drag it from my cell to my destination view and there I configured the segue identifier

Comment: Ok I did it (I deleted the segue from the cell I dragged a new one from the view controller itself

Answer (score 0):

to add to the first comment, I did it like this with the use of a UISwitch in a header cell with a  bool variable declared in the top of the class

```
@IBAction func `switchAction`(_ sender: UISwitch) {
selected = sender.isOn
    if selected == false {
        //do you stuff here change false to true if you need it that way
    }
}
```

then in this method setup like this

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    var enable: Bool = false
    if selected == false {
        enable = true
    } else {
        enable = false
    }

    return enable
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I found a solution from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

you can use block- closesure

```
 var alertAction :((result:Bool)->())?
```

use it  :

```
 alertView.addButton("Second") {
    alertAction?(false)
}
```

implement:

```
alertAction = {result in
    // do s.t
}
```